# uvicorn and fastAPI with pyinstaller problem when uvicorn

Tags: uvicorn

if `uvicorn main:app --reload` return `uvicorn main:app --reload // Command 'uvicorn' not found, but can be installed with: sudo apt install uvicorn`
try with this command:

```
 python -m uvicorn main:app --reload
```

Comment: I think you should install `uvicorn` using `pip` with your package manager or add it to your requirements.txt/setup.cfg for your app.